# Error installing coremltools

Tags: python, ios, swift, coreml

I am looking at Core ML Apple iOS framework. I have read that to install coremltools to create own models. I have installed python `sudo python /Users/administrator/Downloads/get-pip.py`

As per document [coreml installation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools) I have downloaded coremltool file.

and then trying to install `coremltools`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools

When I installed coremltools on my mac, i got the following error. Please suggest me to solve this error. so that i can work on `coremltools`

```
MyMacbook:~ administrator$ pip install -U /Users/administrator/Downloads/coremltools-0.3.0-py2.7-none-any.whl 
Processing ./Downloads/coremltools-0.3.0-py2.7-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.6.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from coremltools==0.3.0)
Collecting protobuf>=3.1.0 (from coremltools==0.3.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.9 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from protobuf>=3.1.0->coremltools==0.3.0)
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.1.0->coremltools==0.3.0)
  Using cached setuptools-36.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, coremltools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 18.5
    Uninstalling setuptools-18.5:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/h1/z0gcmgkx6b9_l2_zpyzvl7tm0000gn/T/pip-DFHVSK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
MyMacbook:~ administrator$
```

Comment: Try prefixing your command with `sudo`

Comment: I tried but same error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're trying to change your system Python. That's why it says `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted`. To avoid messing up system libraries, you need to create separate Python virtual environment. This is how to do it:

1. Upgrade pip:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pip
   ```
2. Install [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

   ```
   pip install –U virtualenv
   ```
3. Create new virtual environment:

   ```
   cd ~
   virtualenv coreml
   ```

   This creates folder `~/coreml/` and a local copy of Python, pip and all other stuff you need for work.
4. To activate virtual environment:

   ```
   source coreml/bin/activate
   ```

   Now you see in your terminal `(coreml)` prepends your user name.
5. In newly created virtual environment:

   ```
   pip install -U coremltools
   ```
6. Check that library was installed successfully:

   ```
   python
   import coremltools
   ```

   There should not be any error messages.
7. To deactivate virtual environment run:

   ```
   deactivate
   ```

Note: [Never run](https://askubuntu.com/a/802594) `pip` with `sudo`. If you need sudo, 99% chance you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed steps. It worked all the way. When I did the step 6, no errors. I really don't know what to do next, i mean using 'coremltools' how to create own ML models and use for Xcode project.

Comment: They have a documentation on how to use it, [for sklearn for example](http://pythonhosted.org/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert.html#coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert). There are [some tutorials](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/machine-learning-in-ios-using-core-ml/) on how to import those into an iOS projects. But if you don't have previous experience with machine learning, this won't help much. If this is the case, try to start from some scikit-learn tutorials and courses on Coursera.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is really helps a lot..I did machine learning course already...If you find any other tutorials for using Apple coreml tools to create own models, kindly keep sharing it. thank you very much.

Comment: Just to clarify things, you can't create your own models using coreml, because [it is not a machine learning framework](http://alexsosn.github.io/ml/2017/06/09/Core-ML-will-not-Work-for-Your-App.html). To create models you use scikit-learn, Keras, XGBoost etc and then use coreml to convert those models to Apple "mlmodel" format. Coremltools is a bunch of scripts to convert pre-trained models to this new format.

Comment: An alternative to the steps above is to install python with `brew install python`, which includes `pip`. Then simply run `pip install -U coremltools.`

Answer (score 1):

Is their a specific reason, that you downloaded the .whl-file?

You cloud try to install directly from PyPI with:

```
pip install -U coremltools
```

This is the recommended way as shown in the [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools), you already posted.

Note: I know this is not a very sophisticated answer, but I do not have enough reputation to just comment.

Comment: Ok. I don't know the documentation is not clear. I just downloaded this file. Anyway, As you said, I tried 'pip install -U coremltools' but observed the exact same errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/apple/coremltools
```

i installed it on windows it works:)

Answer (score -1):

For COREML : Following steps needed :

1. Check if python available -   `python --version`
2. Install Java runtime from Oracle website for Mac 64 bit
3. Then `sudo python -m ensurepip`.  to install PIP .
4. Install coremltools for Mac - `pip3 install -U pip setuptools`

UPDATE: Python 3
If you install python 3, pip will be installed automatically.

```
brew install python3
```

Answer (score -1):

My success story;

1. **pyhton --version**

   if it is 3.xxx, you don't need to create a virtualenv.
2. **cd ~**
3. **sudo pip install coremltools**

   if you can't find some functions, to illustrate I can't find conversion for cafee model (coremltools.converters.caffe.convert), then I used the following command

   **sudo pip install coremltools==4.0**

then I would able to convert the model using coremltools.

Comment: `sudo pip install ...` risks breaking software that relies on the system Python, that's why using a virtualenv is recommended.